# How to improve low throughput groupbykey in dataflow pipeline

Tags: group-by, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, key-value

I have an apache beam batch pipeline (written in java) to transform raw analytics data from bigquery into an aggregated form. Session records (that might now be extended by the next days worth of page events) and a new set of page events are read from bigquery. The pipeline is then performing a `groupByKey` operation to group by user id (across both datasets) before the aggregation operation to create session records. The `groupByKey` operation is performing very slowly (a throughput of ~50 per sec) on the larger dataset (~8400000 records) whereas the throughput for the other input (~1000000 records) was much much higher (~10000 per sec). Does anyone have any advice on how I can troubleshoot and ultimately improve the speed of the operation?

From research online I am aware sometimes it can be more efficient to use a `Combine` operation rather than `groupByKey` ( among others this [article](https://blog.softwaremill.com/let-mortal-combat-begin-apache-beams-groupbykey-vs-combine-perkey-29e4feb7291?gi=e203f497d9cf)) but I did not think that would be appropriate for the data I'm grouping (BQ TableRow records).

Further info that might be useful:

- The `groupByKey` is taking the 8400000 into approx 3500000 grouped records with a range of ~2000 to 1 records being combined per key
- I fully acknowledge I am lacking a full understanding of the intricacies of apache beam and dataflow and am keen to understand a lot more as I will be building out a number of different pipelines.
- Below is a screenshot of the dataflow graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Individual stages in Beam get [fused together](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-example) when running on Dataflow, meaning the throughput of on stage gets tied to others, so it's fully possible it's not the GroupByKey but rather adjacent DoFns that are causing the slowness. If you click on a step you can see, the step-info tab, a field that gives the wall time for executing a particular step. I would see if there is a particular step in your pipeline around that GroupByKey that has a high walltime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took a look into this and unfortunately its definitely the GroupByKey itself that is causing the slowness

Comment: Are the data sizes similar for both?